# WinXP Only Bitmap.Save ArgumentException Parameter Not Valid

Tags: c#-4.0, gdi+, bit-manipulation

Basically the code is trying to take a source image, draw some custom text on it and save the new image to the file system.

When I run the code in Windows 7, it runs fine, but when I run it in WinXP it creates an exception in the imgCopy.Save line anytime after the first DrawString.

The exception is ArgumentException (parameter is not valid). It's like the DrawString corrupts the image under WinXP...?

The build is for the x86/.NET 4.0 runtime. Any ideas why the exception under XP?

```
// imgSrc is actually passed into the method with the rec object
// this is just for repro
using (var imgSrc = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(rec.SrcFile))
using (var imgCopy = imgSrc.Clone() as Bitmap)
using (var gImg = Graphics.FromImage(imgCopy)) //shorten var names for this post
{
    imgCopy.Save(rec.DstFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Happy here
    gImg.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    imgCopy.Save(rec.DstFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Also no problem
    gImg.DrawString(rec.Name, fntArial16, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(170, 105, 650, 50), sfCenter);
    imgCopy.Save(rec.DstFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //<-- Fails here
}
```

Edit: Code for the parameters:

```
private static Font fntArial16 = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);

private static StringFormat _sfCenter;
private static StringFormat sfCenter {
    get {
        if (_sfCenter == null) {
            _sfCenter = new StringFormat();
            sfCenter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sfCenter.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        }
        return _sfCenter;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what format is the original file?

Comment: Just a note too: smoothing doesn't work for text. Use `gimg.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;` for text.

Comment: Sorry, it's also a jpg file. Thanks, I'll change the TextRenderHint.

Comment: I replicated your code (made a simple class with the properties in the example as well as a stringformat to center text) and I could not produce the error on a xp/32-bit machine using .net 4. There isn't anything in your code that should indicate a problem neither. It could be a problem with the image file itself (is it gray-scale or in a special format?). If possible, please share the image in an original state (use a share file service). Could you also post the code for the fntArial16 and sfCenter allocations.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the source image, but I have created a file from a screen shot it it didn't error?!? What questions do I need to ask our graphic artist about XP specific requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We narrowed the problem down to the .jpg file containing XMP (Extensible Metadata Platform) data. Once we removed that from the file it worked on WinXP correctly. Unfortunately the tool that generated the file didn't have the option to exclude this, so we went with the .png file instead and that works fine as well.